# Hiding navbar on scroll does not make navbar fixed in place after scrolling up

Tags: javascript, html, css, navbar

I'm working on a project that add navbar items dynamically. It works so well, but my problem is that I'm trying to make the navbar hidden when user is scrolling down and appears once he scroll up. I also want it to be fixed in place at all time at the top of my screen. Everything worked as it should except when I added the hide navbar on scroll function (Last couple of lines in my JS snippet).

(I just started working on this project last night is it's very messy and not polished at all, but I'll work on styling and everything once I'm done with JS file)

Here's a snippet from my code:

```js
// Assigning variables to elemets
const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
const menubar = document.querySelector('.menu-icon');
const navbar = document.querySelector('nav');
const navbarList = document.querySelector('ul');
const sections = document.querySelectorAll('section');

// Dropdown menu on click
menubar.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (navbar.style.visibility === 'hidden') {
    navbar.style.visibility = 'visible';
  } else {
    navbar.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  }
});

// Hide Dropdown menu when scrolling

document.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  navbar.style.visibility = 'hidden';
});

// Populate navbar
function navbarItems(id, name) {
  const navItem = `<a class="nav-link" href="#${id}"> ${name}</a>`;
  return navItem;
}

function populateNavbar() {
  for (let i = 0; i < sections.length; i++) {
    const newItem = document.createElement('li');
    const sectionName = sections[i].getAttribute('name');
    const sectionId = sections[i].getAttribute('id')
    newItem.innerHTML = navbarItems(sectionId, sectionName);
    navbarList.appendChild(newItem);
  }
  navbarList.appendChild(fragment);
}

populateNavbar();

//

// In viewport detection
function isInViewport(elem) {
  const bounding = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
  return (
    (bounding.top + bounding.bottom) >= 0 &&
    bounding.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight)

  );
};

// Active section
const subMenuItems = document.querySelectorAll('li');

function activeSection() {
  for (let i = 0; i < sections.length; i++) {
    if (isInViewport(sections[i])) {
      sections[i].classList.add('active-section');
    } else {
      sections[i].classList.remove('active-section');
    };

    if (sections[i].classList.contains('active-section')) {
      subMenuItems[i].classList.add('active-nav-item');
    } else {
      subMenuItems[i].classList.remove('active-nav-item');
    }
  }
};

// Hide navbar on scroll down
document.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  activeSection();
  // This is the bad part
  if (window.scrollY > 0) {
    document.querySelector('header').style.top = '-160px';

  } else {
    document.querySelector('header').style.top = '0';
  }
  // ^^
});
```

```css
/* Mobile-First approach */

header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  width: 100%;
  height: 110px;
  background-color: #22292F;
  padding: 10px 0;
  margin: 0;
  transition: top 0.3s;
}

.nav-wrap {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0 15px;
  align-content: center;
}

.logo {
  height: 3em;
  align-self: center;
  margin: 0.8em;
}

.menu-icon {
  font-size: 2em;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 50px;
  align-self: center;
}

nav {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  background-color: #3D4852;
  top: 8em;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
}

.nav-list {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.active-nav-item {
  background-color: peru;
}

.nav-link {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 12px;
  color: #DAE1E7;
  text-decoration: none;
  letter-spacing: 0.05em;
  font-size: 1em;
  text-align: center;
}

.nav-link:hover,
.nav-link:focus {
  color: #eb6f4a;
}

.container {
  padding-top: 130px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxst.icons8.com/vue-static/landings/line-awesome/line-awesome/1.3.0/css/line-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <!-- navbar section -->
  <header>
    <div class="nav-wrap">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="Logo" class="logo">
      <nav>
        <ul class="nav-list">
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <i class="las la-bars menu-icon"></i>

    </div>
  </header>
  <div class="container">
    <!-- first section -->
    <section id="section1" name="section 1">
      <div class="box">
        <img class="images" src="https://picsum.photos/400" alt="">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
          irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      </div>
    </section>

    <!-- second section -->
    <section id="section2" name="section 2">
      <div class="box">
        <img class="images" src="https://picsum.photos/400" alt="">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
          irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      </div>
    </section>

    <!-- third section -->
    <section id="section3" name="section 3">
      <div class="box">
        <img class="images" src="https://picsum.photos/400" alt="">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
          irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      </div>
    </section>

    <!-- fourth section -->
    <section id="section4" name="section 4">
      <div class="box">
        <img class="images" src="https://picsum.photos/400" alt="">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
          irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      </div>
    </section>

    <!-- Fifth section -->
    <section id="section5" name="section 5">
      <div class="box">
        <img class="images" src="https://picsum.photos/400" alt="">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
          irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      </div>
    </section>
    <footer>
      <a href="#"><i class="lab la-github"></i></a>
      <a href="#"><i class="lab la-twitter"></i></a>
      <a href="#"><i class="lab la-linkedin-in"></i></a>
    </footer>
  </div>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have to do these kind of stuffs it is simple and easy. The same is given in w3schools official website. The code is given below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#navbar {
  background-color: #333;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  transition: top 0.3s;
}

#navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

#navbar a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="navbar">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
</div>

<div style="padding:15px 15px 2500px;font-size:30px;margin-top:30px;">
  <p><b>This example demonstrates how to hide a navbar when the user starts to scroll the page.</b></p>
  <p>Scroll down this frame to see the effect!</p>
  <p>Scroll up to show the navbar.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor dummy text sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor dummy text sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>

<script>
var prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;
window.onscroll = function() {
var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
  if (prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos) {
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.top = "0";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.top = "-50px";
  }
  prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. It worked but I needed to change pageYOffset to scrollY for it work properly on my project. I don't know why this is the case, but nonetheless, thank you so much again.